# Get indices of top N values from list in the order of the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list like `a=[3,5,7,12,4,1,5]` and need to get the indices of the top `K(=3)` elements of this list, in the order of the elements. So in this case, result should be

```
[3,2,1]
```

since top 3 elements are `12, 7, 5` (last one is tie so first index is returned).

What is the simplest way to get this?

Comment: Sort the list of indices according to their corresponding values, then slice the first K values.

Comment: shouldn't the 0 be 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is tagged [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), you can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on the opposite values (for reverse sorting), then slice to get the `K` desired values:

```
a = np.array([3,5,7,12,4,18,1,5,18])
K = 3
out = np.argsort(-a)[:K]
```

output: `array([3, 2, 1])`

If you want the indices in order of the original array but not necessarily sorted themselves in order of the values, you can also use [`numpy.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
out = np.argpartition(a, K)[-K:]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean 3,2,1 right?

```
[a.index(i) for i in sorted(a)[:3:-1]]
```

Answer (score -3):

Personally, I would create a sorted list through the `sorted` method, then compare the first `K` values with the `.index` attribute of a. This will yield you your desired result.

```
K = 3 #Number of elemens

a = [3,5,7,12,4,1,5]

a_sorted = sorted(a,reverse=True)

b = [a.index(v) for v in a_sorted[:K]]
print(b)
>>> [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This would not return the indices of the top 3 elements, it will print the top 3 elements.

Comment: The complexity of sorting, then using `index` would not be ideal. Better do everything in one shot